# DocuSign Embedded Sending - Link in Email Message

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign Embedded Sending interface.
In the Email Blurb, I want to add in a link for example:

```
<a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Sample Link</a>
```

However, after the setup, the interface changes the blurb setup from string to HTML and what appears under the DocuSign embedded interface is the following:

```
&lt;a href='http://www.yahoo.com'&gt;Sample Link &lt;/a&gt;
```

Is there anyway I can escape the special characters for the embedded interface?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question: the email blurb is sent to recipients, including signers. But if you want your signers to use your own app (including embedded signing) then the recipients won't/shouldn't get the email... Do you want the signers to receive an email invitation to sign? If so, why not have them sign via the usual DocuSign signing experience (not embedded)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's possible to achieve what you're trying to achieve (i.e., add HTML to email blurb via API), but you'll have to ask DocuSign to enable a setting for your account. The setting you want them to enable is called `Allow HTML input in the API`.

Contact either your DocuSign Account Manager (if you have one) or DocuSign Support (if you don't have an Account Manager), to ask that the ability to insert HTML into notification emails be enabled for your DocuSign account (`Allow HTML input in the API`). If you contact Support (support@docusign.com), be sure to provide your account number and tell them which environment (demo or prod) the account resides in.

Comment: Thanks Kim. Will update this as the answer once I get them to enable it and verify this. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be interested to hear the results. While I'm hopeful that this solves your problem, I do wonder whether or not the DocuSign Sending UI disallows HTML tags altogether and automatically escapes any characters like < >.  i.e., it's possible that even though enabling the setting would allow you to create AND send an Envelope where the email blurb contains HTML tags that your API request specifies -- seems like there's still a chance that the HTML characters might be automatically escaped by the UI form when you create the Envelope via API but then launch the embedded sending view.